# MacのVSCodeでpythonファイルを開くときにpython3のインストールを促すポップアップが出てくる

Tags: python, macos, vscode, anaconda

Macbook pro(MacOSバージョン10.15.5)でVisual Studio Code+anacondaを使ってpythonを書こうとしていますが、pythonファイルを開くたびにpython3のインストールを促すポップアップが出てきてしまいます。（添付の画像参照）
ポップアップが出る原因＆対処方法を教えてほしいです。

＜事象発生までの流れ＞
VSCodeを開く
↓
pythonファイルを開く
↓
python3.7.6 64-bit('base':conda)のインタプリタが選択される
↓
python3のインストールを促すポップアップが表示される
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

※VSCodeのユーザ設定は下記のパラメータに"/Users/<ユーザ名>/opt/anaconda3/bin/python"を入れてます。
・python.pythonPath
・python.defaultInterpreterPath
※私の推測ではpythonのインタープリタを選択する内部処理で、一覧に最初(一番上）に表示されるpython2.7（macに標準で入っているもの）が最初に選択され、その後にpython3.7.6の指定を行うため、ポップアップが出てしまうのではないかと考えています。（仕様というかバグというか・・・）インタープリタの一覧でpython3.7.6を一番上に持ってこれたら解決できるのでは？と考えていますが、その方法もあるかどうかわかっていません。

Comment: VSCode のバージョンはいくつでしょうか？　また、どちらにせよ Command Line Tools はインストールしておいた方が色々と便利な気がしますがインストールしない理由があるのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。VSCodeのバージョンは1.46.0です。anacondaでpython3が既に入っているのに、別バージョンのpython3が意図せずインストールされてしまうのが嫌だった、という理由です。あと、トラブルを切り分けて納得できる回答が知りたい、というのもあります。結局、ポップアップ通り、インストールしてしまいました。原因は気になるところですが、一旦このまま使います。

Comment: バージョン情報ありがとうございます。古い VSCode だと https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70248 のような issue があったのでバージョンを伺いました。

Comment: `python.condaPath` は指定なさっていますか？